# Issue about Leela Zero

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio-code, clone

Hello dear community !

I'm very new to code, so excuse me for advance if I'm unclear. I'll try to be as precise as possible. I've a simple request, which I'm quite sure the understanding of the problem is simplistic. I wanna use Lizzie, a piece of software to analyze a Go Game using Leela Zero. Unfortunately, I have issues installing Leela Zero.

When I try to simply execute the MakeFile, here is what I get: [issue trying to use the MakeFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zijP.png)

Understanding a path issue with that Eigen include, I dig and find this: [path issue with CPUPipe.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvg9h.jpg)

Very precisely, the error is:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. 
Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit 
(/Applications/leela-zero/src/CPUPipe.cpp).
```

([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRgNH.jpg))

So I started thinking my VSCode wasn't fully equipped for C++ standards, but after downloading packaging vscode-cpptools, the make is still not processing.

I hope I'm not terribly expliciting my problem, due to the whole lack of knowledge I have in IT, but I hope maybe someone could help me with that path problem.

Question by the way: should I git clone my stuff in my home dir, or am I mistaken and I should do it directly into the Applications repository ?

Many thanks for anyone that may help ! Don't hesitate to ask question and screens for more details from my side.

Cheers =)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: Hi, I think that as a mac user it should be easier to install the available package [install-leela-zero](https://github.com/leela-zero/leela-zero/tree/next#i-just-want-to-play-with-leela-zero-right-now), instead of building it from scratch

Comment: You definitely fixed my Leela Zero problem with that. Thank you so much, I'm done with it, so thank you =) @joepol !

Now, still have issues with Lizzie. Once I'm lauching the Lizzie.jar, it seems to start, but once I'm about to start to use it, it crashes at once saying "The Java JAR file "lizzie.jar" could not be launched. Still a path issue ?

Comment: @BrunoVERCHERE do you run it as mentioned here: [running-lizzie](https://github.com/featurecat/lizzie#running-lizzie), note they also explain you might need to update `config.txt`

Comment: @joepol If was doing this part right, but I forgot a fundamental step. All the Leela Zero were running good, but I missed to cp the exe into the Lizzie folder which is just absolutely basic. Everything works well now !

Thank you so so much =)